# An internal ip thats not on my dhcp clients list

Tags: wireless-networking, router, virtualbox, wireshark, smart-tv

I ran wireshark and saw some traffic in my VirtualBox Host-Only network. I do use virtual box to learn kali linux, but it is not running right now.

When I clicked to see whats going on, I saw an IP `192.168.1.56`, that is not present on my client list on my router interface.

I searched what I saw in the 'info' field on wireshark (urn:: dial multiscreen-org ..) and see that its about smart tv's which we own one and on some other packets i saw the word "spotify" as well.

Can someone explain why I'm seeing this, and if it's my TV generating this traffic, why it isn't shown on my DHCP list on my router?

[image: wireshark]

[image: clients list]

Comment: DHCP is used for automatic IP assignment, but you can manually set static IPs as well.

Comment: According to wireshark, the traffic came from your router - your router may have some functionality where it connects to spotify clients?; Also, the IP you've listed in your question `192.168.1.57` doesn't match what's in the screenshots, you've swapped the last two digits around.

Comment: "if it's my TV generating this traffic"  You tell us -- if you disconnect your TV from the network, does this suspect traffic stop?  "why it isn't shown on my DHCP list" When you looked a the TV's network settings, was it set to use DHCP to get it's address?

Comment: i ran zenmap now on 192.168.1.*  , and still there is no device with the address 192.168.1.56